# Is v.surf.mass not available anymore in the recent versions of GRASS GIS? If so, why?

Tags: grass-gis

I wanted to use the tool v.surf.mass, [described here in the docs from GRASS GIS 7.0](http://wgbis.ces.iisc.ernet.in/grass/grass70/manuals/addons/v.surf.mass.html). However, this tool does not seem to be available on the newer versions (tried 7.6, 7.8 and 8.0). When I type
`v.surf.mass --help` 
on the GRASS GIS console, a message saying the command was not found is shown.
Investigating the user manual, the tool is not described there, which makes me wonder if it was removed in one of the releases.

Does anyone know if v.surf.mass was removed from GRASS GIS, and if yes, why?

Comment: Note that the manual there is totally outdated. Go here for the latest and official addon manuals: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass80/manuals/addons/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This tool is in the grass-addons, as shown here: https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/tree/grass8/src/vector/v.surf.mass

You can install it using the extension manager (`Settings` -> `Addon extensions` -> `Install extensions from addons`), and in other ways as shown in https://grass.osgeo.org/download/addons/